# How to restore dump without drop table before in MySql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a dump of a part of a table from specific date and I would like to restore this dump in a replica database in the specific table, but when I try to restore it, the mysql gives me an error: `The table is already exist`.

In case it helps, the way I do the dump is the next:

`mysqldump --user=root my_db my_table --where="YEAR(created)='2021' AND MONTH(created)='21'" > week21.sql`

I know that I can create the dump with `--opt`option, but this option drop first the whole table, so I would lose the current data in this table right?

Any Idea to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What form is your dump in? Is it a text file containing INSERT commands (among other bits)? If so edit it, remove the DROP instructions

Comment: How the dump looks like? Does it inserts SQLs?

Comment: Your next issue may be duplicate keys, but thats for another question, and shoudl include and bit more info about the table(s) in question

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I cant remove the drop, but if I remove it, I get the error I described in the OP: `The table is already exist`

Comment: What are your cases? I am suggesting you to dump this table with different name, TABLE_A_21_2021. In addition you can create stored procedures that can merge the content into the main table if needed.

Comment: you should have created the dump with this option: `-t, --no-create-info`.  The `DROP TABLE`, and `CREATE TABLE` will not be in the dumpfile.  Your current option is to remove the `DROP` and `CREATE` from the dumpfile.

Comment: SO Remove the CREATE TABLE instructions as well, just leave the INSERT's

Comment: Are these data records updateable?

Comment: Create the dump without CREATE TABLE statements (see according command-line options in RM). OR edit your dump and replace all `CREATE TABLE` with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`. But remember that the dump importing may cause duplicate violation if dump data interferes with existing data by some column/expression which is defined as unique.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) (or [mariadb-dump](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-dumpmysqldump/)) emits a mess of SQL statements into its output file. You can read those statements by looking at the file in a text editor. And, you can edit the file if need be (but that's a brittle way to handle a workflow like yours).

You need to get it to write the correct SQL statements for your particular application. In your case the `CREATE TABLE` statements mess up your workflow, so leave them out.

If you use the [command-line option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-create-info) `--no-create-info` mysqldump won't write `CREATE TABLE` statements into its output file. So that will solve your immediate problem.

If the rows you attempt to restore with your mysqldump output might already exist in your new table, you can use mysqldump's `--insert-ignore` [command line option](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore) to get it to write [INSERT IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) statements rather than plain INSERT statements.